# VectorWriter analog in QGIS 3 API

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

It seems that in API for QGIS 3 VectorWriter was replaced:

`from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter` returns 
`ImportError: cannot import name 'VectorWriter'`. 
How do I rewrite following things for PyQGIS 3?

```
writer = VectorWriter(output, None, fields,
                              QGis.WKBMultiPolygon, input_layer.crs())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can migrate the VectorWriter with QgsVectorFileWriter in Qgis 3, such as:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsWkbTypes

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(output, "System", fields, QgsWkbTypes.MultiPolygon, crs, "ESRI Shapefile")
f = QgsFeature(...)
writer.addFeature(f)
```